# Excel - slicers copying each other

Tags: excel, filter, slicers

I have an Excel spreadsheet which is split down the middle and mirrored on the other side so I do comparisons. I have the same slicers on both sides but when I change one slicer the other changes too. Is there a way to make the slicers independent from each other? When you change the Report Connections on one slicer this is also copied on the other one. I have two pivot tables which are showing the same data but I just want to slice them differently.

I have now duplicated my raw data as a workaround but this seems unnecessary to do.

Comment: Do you know how to use a separate cache for each?

Comment: When you say "split down the middle" are you referring to the effect you get when using the 'Split' or 'Freeze Panes' functionality under the View tab? If so, note that this functionality doesn't create separate pivots/slicers but just  serves up two 'views' of the exact same thing.

Comment: Dean: Can you please comment on my answer below, so we know whether this solved the issue. (And if it did solve the issue, can you please accept the answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what has happened is that at some stage you connected both Slicers to both Pivots. When this happens, Excel then forever treats both Slicers as just one, and you can't separate them again so that they point at different Pivots. I blogged about this some time back at the following link:

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/05/slicers-and-slicercaches/

If this is the case, all you need to do is delete one of the Slicers, and create a new one on the other PivotTable.